# Get error when try to use `\1` which get from regex `(\d)?` in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace, capture-group

**Example code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

print re.sub(r'a+(\d)?', r'\1', "aaaa3")
print re.sub(r'a+(\d)?', r'\1', "aaaa") # error!
```

The second `print` statement gives me an error:

```
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bbb.py", line 5, in <module>
    print re.sub(r'a+(\d)?', r'\1', "aaaa")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 291, in filter
    return sre_parse.expand_template(template, match)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 831, in expand_template
    raise error, "unmatched group"
sre_constants.error: unmatched group
```

How can I deal with this capturing variable with a probable quantifier `0` without an error?

**Note** `(\d)?` here can be another complicated regex, not just an easy as `\d`, that why I bring my quantifier `?` out out `(..)`.

Comment: Move the `?` inside the capture group.

Comment: In Python, you cannot back-reference failed (unmatched)  capturing groups. But you can in JavaScript :)

Comment: I try this easy code on https://regex101.com/#python, it's work but on my terminal, it doesn't work, then I'm a bit confused. Any way thank you for your responses.

Comment: @stribizhev your information couple with  a note about Javascript should be helpful, please answer below.

Comment: I guess the currently accepted answer explains it all, no need flooding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python you can do this to get an empty back-reference of an optional group:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'a+(\d?)', r'\1', "aaaa")

>>> print re.sub(r'a+(\d?)', r'\1', "aaaa123")
123
```

i.e. use `(\d?)` instead of `(\d)?`

Python regex engine unlike many other regex engines doesn't populate back-references when corresponding capturing group fails to match a pattern.